# Is is possible to create UI Form creation in Qt with the help of JSON files

Tags: c++, json, qt

Suppose There is a QWidget in Qt which displays the Employee data

Checkbox options View(Default) Edit()

QLabel Name  Value
QLabel Age   Value

In traditional Qt programming it will be implemented with the help of a QWidget in Qt designer or the cpp code.

So I have two questions
1. If it will be efficient to create the UI on the basis of a json file rather then these two methos? 
2. If I can design the signal and slot at the run time with JSON in form of relation among the different GUI elements. e.g. Edit clicked and GUI enabled.  View Clicked GUI disabled.

Comment: Anything is *possible* if you put enough work into it. Sure, if you want to write a JSON parser that can convert some JSON representation of a GUI into Qt C++, then you *could do that*. The question then becomes whether it's worth the effort (I doubt it).

Comment: You are trying to re-invent [QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can but you cannot expect this functionality to be there because it is not. You will have to write some code to process the JSON files and convert those to widgets. Qt supports reading and writing JSON data out of the box so all you have to do is tell (through code) how that data is to be interpreted.

This "exercise" is useful only in very limited scenarios where you don't want to go with the **ui** and **qml** mechanisms that Qt offers. Before you decide to go down that road invest some time thinking whether your scenario is appropriate.